# How to create history data for testing on stripe.com

Tags: testing, stripe-payments

I am working on integrating stripe.com for payment in my application and writing some analytics also on top of that data.

I am not able to figure out how to create history data for testing on stripe.com . Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now it's not possible to create a stripe account with past transactional data or to add data with past dates. You can create a script to populate an account with some test data or you can also use stripe dashboard to create test data at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/dashboard. For more information on testing and test card numbers to create various events in your Stripe account check
- https://stripe.com/docs/testing

Check my blog on this topic - 
https://www.stripetics.com/blog/past-data-stripe-testing/

Comment: Is it possible to add data with future dates ?

Comment: I am not sure if there could be a possible use case for this but again its not possible to add data with future dates either. You can have subscriptions which will get activated in future date but that is not exactly adding data for future dates.